# Accessing register depending their address

Tags: verilog

Does anyone know the *Verilog* code to select single register from the register list depending on the address of the register?

For Example

```
+------+--------------+---------+
| Name | Offset_value | Address |
+------+--------------+---------+
| Reg1 |           01 | 0x00    |
| Reg2 |           00 | 0x04    |
| Reg3 |           00 | 0x08    |
| Reg4 |           00 | 0x0C    |
+------+--------------+---------+
```

If I give address as 0x08, then I can read/write from Reg3 and so on.
Each register is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description you have multiple flip-flops or registers that you want to update based on a write address.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  case ( address )
    8'h00 : Reg1 <= data;
    8'h04 : Reg2 <= data;
  endcase
end
```

If however you wanted to uses memory structure instead of REG1/2/3

```
reg [7:0] Reg_dat [0:254]; //255 8bit locations
always @(posedge clk) begin
  Reg_dat[address] <= data;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Morgan suggested, you can use flop based memory to make reg bank,

```
reg [7:0] Reg_dat [0:254]; //255 8bit locations
always @(posedge clk) begin
  Reg_dat[write_reg_address] <= wr_reg;
end
```

For writing particular reg, you have to provide write_reg_address and value which you want to be write in register.

For reading of specific register value, you have to provide only read_reg_address and it gives value of that particular reg.

```
assign read_reg = Reg_dat[read_reg_address];
```